# Appear of random UIbutton using Tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, uibutton

I am having 20 buttons now. And all of them will be hidden at the beginning.
Then i want e.g. 5 buttons of among the 20 buttons appear randomly.

I tired to use tag function in UIButton. But don't know how to code them to appear randomly.

Thanks

Comment: Are the buttons added with IB or in code?

Comment: In Interface Builder. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an IBOutletCollection in your code with something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

In IB, drag an outlet for each button to this outlet collection.

To randomly select buttons, use this snippet in a loop or something to get one of the buttons randomly.

```
UIButton *randomButton = self.buttons[arc4random_uniform(self.buttons.count)];
```

From here, you could keep a list of which buttons have been shown, or after viewDidLoad create an array in the class that's a copy of the 'buttons' array and remove things as you show them and randomly select from there, or whatever you'd like.